# fetching substring with a condition from another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data sets, 1 with only address like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Address": ["36 omar st, pal, galambo","33 pom kopd malan", "15 kop st,dogg, ghog", "23 malo st, pal, kola"]})

                    Address
0  36 omar st, pal, galambo
1         33 pom kopd malan
2      15 kop st,dogg, ghog
3     23 malo st, pal, kola
```

and the other is a dataset with every state and the cities inside of it

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"State": ["galambo", "ghog", "ghog", "kola", "malan", "malan"], "City": ["pal", "dogg", "kopd", "kop", "pal", "kold"]})

     State  City
0  galambo   pal
1     ghog  dogg
2     ghog  kopd
3     kola   kop
4    malan   pal
5    malan  kold
```

I'm trying to fetch state name and city name out of each address, so I tried this

```
df["State"] = df['Address'].apply(lambda x: next((a for a in df2["State"].to_list() if a in x), np.nan))
df["City"] = df['Address'].apply(lambda x: next((a for a in df2["City"].to_list() if a in x), np.nan))

                    Address    State  City
0  36 omar st, pal, galambo  galambo   pal
1         33 pom kopd malan    malan  kopd
2      15 kop st,dogg, ghog     ghog  dogg
3     23 malo st, pal, kola     kola   pal
```

but as you see, the rows 1,3 are incorrect because according to `df2` the State `malan` has no City called `kopd`, and State `kola` has no City called `pal`

so how can I make the output shows only the cities that are in the States as suggested in `df2`?

Update:
Expected output

```
                    Address    State  City
0  36 omar st, pal, galambo  galambo   pal
1         33 pom kopd malan    malan  NaN
2      15 kop st,dogg, ghog     ghog  dogg
3     23 malo st, pal, kola     kola   NaN
```

Comment: Can you provide the explicit expected output?

Comment: @mozway, sure, it's updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `extract` the last matching state/city name, then perform a `merge` to replace the invalid cities by NaN:

```
# craft regexes
regex_state = f"({'|'.join(df2['State'].unique())})"
regex_city = f"({'|'.join(df2['City'].unique())})"

# extract state/city (last match)
df['State'] = df['Address'].str.findall(regex_state).str[-1]
df['City'] = df['Address'].str.findall(regex_city).str[-1]

# fix city
df['City'] = df.merge(df2.assign(c=df2['City']), on=['City', 'State'], how='left')['c']
```

Output:

```
                    Address    State  City
0  36 omar st, pal, galambo  galambo   pal
1         33 pom kopd malan    malan   NaN
2      15 kop st,dogg, ghog     ghog  dogg
3     23 malo st, pal, kola     kola   NaN
```